# Kineticjs object binding

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, layer

I'm creating buttons and label from arrays via loop. I assign layer.id and layer.name to the buttons and labels. What I would like to do when button is pressed, is to draw text, describing the button color, on the appropriate line. The problem is when the button is clicked, the appropriate label is positioned , but only to the last label position and when another button is clicked the caption is written over the last caption. I want to find/assign the appropriate label using l.find("." + v2) I'm using the same function for other parts of the script and the binding works.

```
var s = new Kinetic.Stage({container: 'toolpanel', width:500, height:700});

var l = new Kinetic.Layer();

var cp3 = new Kinetic.Rect({x: 100,y: 10,width: 400,height:700,  stroke:'black', draggable:true});
var db = [];
db.push("red_Glove Type:");
db.push("blue_Glove Type:");
db.push("black_Throws:");
var lx = 50;

for (var i = 0;i < db.length;i++){ var ser = db[i]; var sdb = ser.split("_"); v1 = sdb[0]; v2 = sdb[1];

 var box = new Kinetic.Rect({x: lx+=20 , y:5, fill: v1, id: v2, name:v2,  height: 30, width:30});
 l.add(box); lx+=30; l.draw();

 var posY = box.getPosition().y;
 box.on('mousedown', (function(v1,v2){ return function(){
 var check = l.find("." + "v2");
 var caption = new Kinetic.Text({
 x: 230,
 y:posY ,
 fontSize: 16,
 text: v1, 
 id:v2,
 draggable: true,
 fill:v1
 });
 caption.setText(v1);
  l.add(caption); l.draw();

 }})(v1,v2),false);

 }

var desc = new Kinetic.Text({x: cp3.getWidth()/ 2,y: 20,text: 'Your Personalization',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: 'arial',fill: 'black',padding: 4});
 l.add(desc);

s.add(l);
var odesc = [];
odesc.push("Glove Type:_20");
odesc.push("Glove Series:_40");
odesc.push("Glove Positons:_60");
odesc.push("Throws:_80");
odesc.push("Glove Back Style:_100");
odesc.push("Hand Size:_120");
var ly = 20;

for (var s = 0; s < odesc.length; s++){
var db = odesc[s];
var sdb = db.split("_");
var text = sdb[0];

var label = new Kinetic.Text({ 
x: 100, 
y: ly+=50, 
text: text, 
fontSize: 16 ,
id: text,
fontFamily: 'arial', 
fill: 'black', 
padding: 1, 
align: 'left'
);

l.add(label); ly += 10;
var posY = label.getPosition().y;
} l.draw();
```

Please checkout shortened script[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobsultd/d14a66qg/10/)

Comment: One note, do not use same id for different kinetic objects.

Comment: Thanks.. I thought of this and reason why i added 'name' because it doesn't have to be unique..  in the bigger script, each grouping of buttons will map to specific label.  I'm trying not to write empty text objects for 20 grouping to display to describe the color of object selected, then write if statements against the id to output a specific color..